# Existence of a skew field with surjective inner derivations

Tags: fields, noncommutative-rings

In my research, I've come twice now towards a skew field $K$ that satisfies the following:

> $$\text{for all non-central element $a$, the map }\quad x\mapsto ax-xa\quad\text{ is onto.}$$

I am hoping such a field does not exist but am unable to prove it.

**Does this condition ring a bell** to some of you ?

**Any example of such a field** in both zero and non-zero characteristic ?

**Edit**: reading the paper suggested by @TomDeMedts'comment made me realise that this is precisely Question 3 of http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-03/S0002-9939-1961-0124355-6/ asked by G. Meisters in 1961.

Comment: By $x^a$, you mean $axa^{-1}$ (or with the $a$ switched with $a^{-1}$)? If so, then right multiplication by $a$ is onto, so the question reduces to $x\mapsto ax-xa$ being onto. Certainly seems weird.

Comment: If $K$ is finite-dimensional over its center, then this follows from simple linear algebra since the map ${}^a x - x$ is linear with non-zero kernel. However, as Mariano Suárez-Alvarez pointed out to me in a comment on my now-deleted answer, there exist skew fields $K$ that are infinite-dim'l over their centers, so my argument fails in general.

Comment: Requiring this condition for *all* non-central $a$ seems indeed very restrictive and could potentially lead to a contradiction. On the other hand, already the problem of finding skew fields such that your map is surjective for *some* $a$ is rather challenging, but has been answered by Lazerson in 1961: "Onto inner derivations in division rings", http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1961-67-04/S0002-9904-1961-10613-7/. (Notice that the inner derivations are precisely the maps from @DavidHandelman's comment.)

Comment: @TomDeMedts Many thanks for your comment !

Comment: I've taken the freedom to change your title into a more descriptive one that could potentially attract more views.

Comment: @TomDeMedts Well done :-)

Comment: @TomDeMedts It seems that ref. 4 in your link (G. Meisters, On the equation ax—xb=c in division rings, Abstract 573-8, 
 Notices Amer. Math. Soc. vol. 7 (1960) p. 724.) provides division rings where _all_ non-zero inner derivation in into, which is the question of the MO.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E.: I doubt it, because this problem is phrased as an open question in that paper (Question 3 on p. 431), as the OP pointed out in his Edit.

Comment: @TomDeMedts Sorry. This is a misinterpretation from my side of the sentence [He has shown that (1) ... then $R$ is commutative.] in Lazerson's announcement, due to the absence of an "if" just after (1). I read it too quickly, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *The range of derivations on a skew field and the equation ax-xb=c*, Journal of the Indian Math. Soc. 37 (1973), 61--69, P.M. Cohn shows the following :

> **Theorem (Cohn 1973).** Given a field $K$ with centre $k$, there is an extension field $L$ (still with $k$ as centre) such that the equation $$ax-xa=c$$ has a solution for each $a\in L$ that is transcendental over $k$ and each $c\in L$.

In particular, taking a skew field $K$ having an algebraically closed centre (hence infinite dimentionnal over $k$ as @René notes) provides an $L$ for which every non-zero inner derivation is onto.

Comment: I'm not convinced. I don't have access to the paper, but the Mathematical Review on that paper seems to indicate that only the weaker fact that *some* inner derivation is onto, follows from this. What is the definition of "transcendental" for elements of skew fields, and is it clear that there are no transcendental elements over algebraically closed commutative fields? (I hope this question is not too stupid.)

Comment: @TomDeMedts, as $k$ is the centre of $L$, any extension $k(a)$ with $a\in L$ is commutative, so $a$ transcendental over $k$ is the usual definition. As for your second question, I suppose you mean "is it clear that there are nothing but transcendental elements over algebraically closed commutative fields". And this is clear since not transcendental means algebraic.

Comment: @Drike [there are nothing but transcendental] I think you meant "there are nothing as transcendental", no ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. I mean, there are only transcendental elements.

Comment: @Drike I agree, so my question was indeed rather stupid. Did you state Cohn's result exactly is it was phrased in the paper? (Sorry for insisting!) Did you find the paper somewhere online? (The version that I found in Cohn's book from 1995 (Theorem 8.5.4) is slightly different, and in particular does not mention that $k$ is still equal to the center, which is relevant for your argument.)

Comment: @Drike O.K. (only ... outside $k$), I understand.

Comment: @TomDeMedts Nothing to be sorry about ! I did phrase Cohn's Theorem exactly. I was unable to find it online but I am sending it by email.

Comment: Ok, thanks! You're right, indeed. (I'm a little surprised that neither Cohn himself nor the reviewer on Mathematical Reviews points out that this solves this question of Meisters even though Cohn refers to Meisters' paper.)